# Laravel sail command have no response except sail up and sail down

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-sail

I have a Laravel sail project but when I type sail command there is no reaction in console.

Only `sail up` and `sail down` work fine but other commands like `sail shell`, `sail artisan ***`, `sail php -v` ......donn`t response. No error and no any response.

I wonder what happened?

[image]

Answer (score 21):

If you renamed the laravel.test service to something else you may also set the `APP_SERVICE` variable in your `.env` file to match whatever you renamed it to, this will also work!

*.docker-compose.yml*

```
services:
    app.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - selenium
```

*.env*

```
APP_SERVICE=app.test
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction; I don't know why, but I had to execute sail from vendor, instead of using the alias. `./vendor/bin/sail up -d` did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Ok I know why. I have changed the name `laravel.test` in docker-compose.yml for a new name and it not worked. When I changed back it works again.

Answer (score 2):

You can define an ENV variable `APP_SERVICE` with the value same as you changed for laravel.test in docker-compose.file.